Exploiting MSE of binary data for fast search
I have a huge database of binary vectors. Given an incoming vector, I want to find the closest vector in the database in terms of MSE and return the MSE score. So far I have been doing this search manually, but it takes too long.
Could I exploit characteristics of MSE when used with binary vectors to speed up the search?
More details: I’m looking for. Properties of MSE or Binary Vectors or Data Sparsity that I can exploit to dramatically speed up the search! My dataset has around 4 million high dimensional (~4000) binary vectors, mostly sparse (containing a lot of zeroes). I have a loop that iterates through the 4 million one by one and returns the vector with the lowest MSE score. I cannot use any other metric, and was thinking if any properties of MSE could be exploited to speed up the search. Even if a ML model that uses MSE could be used, it would be perfect

Cool question. In a lower dimension the obvious answer would be a kd-tree https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/kdtrees.pdf. On this high dimension problem it's conceivable that we cannot beat the naive strategy in terms of asymptotic complexity. Of course, this is an embarassingly parallel problem so there's one straightforward way to improve over a serial loop. Is it absolutely, crucially important that you really do get the vector that's closest from your database? Or is it OK if that only happens with high probability, and sometimes we just get a vector that's almost optimal?

Yes, it should be okay to get the vector with a high probability as long as I exploit either the sparsity of the binary vectors or properties of MSE.

You might benefit from appropriating methods from Record Linkage, such as Blocking, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3191

Are the queries (or "incoming vector"s) also sparse?

Yes, they are sparse as well @SimonSegert

There are at least two implementational tricks you can use: 1. vectorized matrix operations and 2. sparse matrix products.
To explain 1, start with the observation that $mse(x,y)=|x|^2+|y|^2-2(x,y)$. In particular, if I have multiple vectors $x_i$ and stack them into the rows of a matrix $X$, then $mse(x_i,y)=|x_i|^2+|y|^2-2(Xy)_i$.
So the problem of computing the mse to each sample point basically comes down to  computing the matrix-vector product $Xy$. The point is that these products are often highly optimized in scientific computing packages (e.g. numpy).
For 2, it sounds like your data is sparse, so using sparse matrix data-types and computing $Xy$ as a sparse product can potentially add another speedup.
Here's a simulation to give you an idea of the differences between implementations. Here, I compare the timings of four methods. The "loop" method uses a for-loop to compute the distance to each row sequentially. The "dense" method expresses X as a dense matrix and uses the previous identity $mse(x_i,y)=|x_i|^2+|y|^2-2(Xy)_i$. The "sparse" method differs from the "dense" method only in that $X$ is expressed as a sparse matrix, and $Xy$ is computed using a sparse matrix product.
For comparisons, I included other methods suggested on this page. The "set" method implements the set-theoretic approach suggested by Alex, using built-in python set operations.
The "slice" method is suggested by Silverfish in the comment to this post and consists of selecting the columns from $X$ that appear in the query, and then summing to obtain the size of the intersection.
Finally the "slice sparse" method is a combination of the slice and sparse methods, and consists of applying the slice method when $X$ is a sparse matrix (although note that it is a different format of sparse matrix than previously).
I used $d=400$ features, $N=10^5$ observations and a sparseness level of 20% (although you can of course adjust these in the code). The timings I get from running the below code on my laptop are:
Loop: .471 s
Set: .410 s
Dense: .105 s
Sparse: .031 s
Slice: .152
Slice sparse: .009
YMMV depending on the level of sparseness in your data.
res={'N':[],'time':[],'method':[]}
N=10**5
n_iters=20
for _ in range(n_iters):
    d=400
    X=np.random.choice(2,size=(N,d),p=[.8,.2])
    sums=X.sum(1).squeeze() #since X is binary, don't have to square
    q=np.random.choice(2,size=d,p=[.8,.2])

    start=time.time()
    min_dist=float('inf')
    for i in range(len(X)):
        dist_i=((X[i]-q)**2).sum()
        min_dist=min(dist_i,min_dist)
    t_loop=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_loop)
    res['method'].append('loop')


    start=time.time()
    (sums-2*X@q).min()
    t_dense=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_dense)
    res['method'].append('dense')


    sets=[set(list(np.where(X[i])[0])) for i in range(len(X))]

    setq=list(np.where(q)[0])
    start=time.time()
    min_dist=float('inf')
    for i,s in enumerate(sets):
        min_dist=min(min_dist,sums[i]-2*len(s.intersection(setq)))
    t_sets=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_sets)
    res['method'].append('sets')
    
    Xcsr=csr_matrix(X)

    start=time.time()
    (sums-2*Xcsr@q).min()
    t_sparse=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_sparse)
    res['method'].append('sparse')



    
    start=time.time()
    (sums-2*X[:,np.where(q)[0]].sum(1).squeeze()).min()
    t_slice=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_slice)
    res['method'].append('slice')
    
    Xcsc=csc_matrix(X)
    start=time.time()
    (sums-2*Xcsc[:,np.where(q)[0]].sum(1).squeeze()).min()
    t_slice2=time.time()-start
    res['N'].append(N)
    res['time'].append(t_slice2)
    res['method'].append('slicesparse')



res=pd.DataFrame(res)
res.groupby('method').mean()


I'm not convinced that the "sets" method here is implemented in a way that puts it in the best light. Rather than using Python's own set objects, something that seems in line with the fundamental idea in the other answer would be to calculate the number of intersections of a given row with the vector q by taking the submatrix containing only columns that correspond to non-zero entries in q and summing up the rows, so something like X[:, q.nonzero()].squeeze().sum(1) maybe? (You'll have to excuse my Python, I'm mostly an R user.)  I found this almost as fast as the sparse matrix method.

Separately, I'm a bit confused by the minimum distances in your code. As far as I can see, the variable sums only counts the ones in each row of X, and then you subtract double the number of intersecting ones between each row of X and the vector q. But don't you also need to add the number of ones in q, so q.sum() or similar? (Not that this will make any significant difference to the execution times, but neither would counting the ones in X since they would be precomputed - which is why it's right that the calculations involving only X  lie outside the timed sections of code.)

@Silverfish, fair point on the implementation, I've updated my answer to include your proposal, as well as a variant where $X$ is also represented as a sparse matrix. The latter variant actually beats the sparse matrix product implementation. But I think the point remains that in order to get this level of performance out of the set idea, the sets should be ultimately represented as some kind of sparse matrix, to take advantage of vectorization.

On your second point, yes I omitted the $|q|$ term from the mse because it is applied the same way for all $x_i$, and can always be added back to the final answer if desired.

I thought that might be the explanation but ran out of room in the comment space to write it :) Minimising $\sum (x_i - y_i)^2 = \sum x_i^2 + \sum y_i^2 - 2 \sum_i x_i y_i$ is equivalent to minimising $\sum x_i^2 - 2 \sum_i x_i y_i$ if $y_i$ is fixed. I was just expecting the function to either return the best matching $x$ or at least the distance of the best-matching row $x$, rather than just a suitable minimand for identifying the best $x$. But I guess you're just providing a timing exercise for the meat of the algorithm rather than a complete solution in the code.

Note that
$$\mathrm{MSE}(x,y) = \frac{d_H(x,y)}{n} \quad\text{for}\quad x,y \in \{0,1\}^n,$$
where $d_H$ denotes Hamming distance. To compute $d_H(x,y)$ rapidly for high-dimensional binary vectors, we can bit-pack each $n$-bit vector $x$ into $\lceil n / 64\rceil$ 64-bit words. Denoting these words by $b_x^1,b_x^2,\ldots$, and similarly $b_q^1,b_q^2,\ldots$ for a query $q$, the Hamming distance is then:
$$d_H(x,q) = \sum_{\ell} \mathrm{popcount}\bigl(b_x^\ell \oplus b_q^\ell\bigr),$$
where $\oplus$ is the bitwise XOR operator, and $\mathrm{popcount}$ counts the number of 1-bits. Many modern CPUs provide hardware-level popcount instructions, making this extremely fast. Storing a database of $N$ vectors in bit-packed form requires far fewer bytes per vector than typical sparse or dense representations, and the XOR/popcount loop can be highly vectorized or parallelized. We can compute $\mathrm{MSE}(x,q) = d_H(x,q)/n$ for each $x$ in the database and retrieve the minimal value in a fraction of the time required by naive methods, all while controlling memory overhead by means of efficient 64-bit packing.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
